# Proving not equicontinuity in $\Bbb R$ but equicontinuity in any other closed subset of $\Bbb R$

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, functions, proof-writing

Let $F = {f_{n} | n ∈\Bbb N }$ be an infinite collection of functions $f_{n}(x)=e^{−n(x−n)^2} , x ∈ \Bbb R$. Prove that $F$ is not equicontinuous on $\Bbb R$ but equicontinuous on $[−a, a]$ for any $a > 0$.

I am trying a modified proof (Initially I posted a proof but didn't reach any conclusions):

First proving not equicontinuous on $\Bbb R$,

$f_{n}(x)=e^{−n(x−n)^2}$

Let $\epsilon =1/2$. let $x=n$

Then, for $|n-y|<\delta$ , we have $|f_{n}(n)-f_{n}(y)|$=$|1-e^{-n(y-n)^2}|\leq 1$.
For $n$ large enough, $|f_{n}(n)-f_{n}(y)|=1>\epsilon$ . So $f_{n}$ is not equicontinuous on $\Bbb R$.

Now proving equicontinuous on $[-a,a], a>0$,

Here lets use the fact that on a compact set, if $f_{n}$ is continuous and if $f_{n}$ converges uniformly on the compact set, then it is equicontinuous on the compact set.

So lets prove that $f_{n}$ converges uniformly on $[-a,a]$. To do this lets first look at the following:

Given an interval $[-a,a]$ and  any $\epsilon>0$.
The pointwise limit of $f_{n}$ is $0$.

Now, what I need to show for uniform convergence is the following:

$$|f_{n}(x)-0|<\epsilon \implies |e^{-n(x-n)^2}|<\epsilon \implies |{n(x-n)^2}|<ln (\epsilon) $$

$$\implies n-\sqrt(ln \epsilon/n)\leq x \leq n+\sqrt(ln \epsilon/n)$$

So for any $a>0$, I can always choose $n$ such that the above condition is satisfied, i.e., $n>a$. hence, $F_{n}$ is equicontinuous on $[-a,a]$

Please check if it is correct. Else suggest a suitable proof.

Comment: Choose $y_n$ so that for all large enough ["large enough" depends on $\delta$ of course] $n$ you have $\lvert y_n - n\rvert < \delta$, but you have $\lvert f_n(y_n) - f_n(n)\rvert > \frac{1}{2}$.

Comment: I am giving a modified idea. Can you please check if it works?

Comment: Modified Proof posted. Please check.

Comment: Can someone please comment on the proof?